# What does "Mackineeks" mean?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

> Big Boss Nass: Who's da uss-en uthers?
>
> Queen: I am Queen Amidala of the Naboo. I come before you in peace.
>
> Big Boss Nass: Naboo biggen. Yousa bringen da **Mackineeks**. Yousa all
> bombad.

What does "Mackineeks" mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a bastardization of "mechanicals". Boss Nass is referring to the battle droids the Trade Federation is dropping on the planet.